# Absolute address of a function in Microchip XC16

Tags: compiler-construction, function-pointers, pic, microchip, xc16

Device: dsPIC33FJ128GP802

I have some *.s files as follows

```
.global _D1
.section .speex, code
_D1:
.pword 0x66C821,  0x1B0090,  0xD96C36,  0x9B60B0,  0xDD4E36,  0xBF4E53
.pword 0xD1098B,  0x719BD9,  0x873989,  0x003B69,  0x279035,  0xED4244
.pword 0xE1403C,  0x54D439,  0x826550,  0xC59627,  0xDD0432,  0x88FA29
```

I have declared the same in a *.h

```
extern void D1(void);
```

Now I am passing the D1 to a table read function

```
nowPlaying.file1 = (unsigned long) D1;
function(nowPlaying.file1);
```

My problem is that, if the address of D1 is above 0x8000, the routine is not correct. I tried large and small code models, but the result is the same. I think this is due to the 16-bit limitation of the pointers. Is there any method to access the absolute address of D1 directly from the code. Maybe something like a built-in function or macros.

Please note that the compiler manual says:

> The MPLAB XC16 C Compiler fully supports pointers to functions, which
>   allows functions to be called indirectly. Function pointers are always
>   16 bits wide.

I have posted the same question at

https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/56858/absolute-address-of-a-function-in-microchip-xc16

Comment: Please clarify, as you have been asked several times, whether the stuff in the .s file is really code or data; please define 'the function is not correct'; and please continue the whole conversation here rather than back at electronics.stackexchange.com where it came from. Otherwise I cannot see the point of you posting here at all.

Answer (score 0):

As I wrote at electronics.stackexchange.com, you are basically lying to the compiler about `D1`, by casting that to `unsigned long`, when it isn't an unsigned long at all. This is very likely to cause problems down the track.

If the stuff starting at D1 is code that can conforms to the C calling conventions, `D1` should be declared as `extern void D1(void)`, and all the struct members and variables and parameters that take its address should be declared as `void (*D1)(void)`, and you can call it via those values with the syntax `(*var)()`. I don't know what the `nowPlaying.file1` variable is for: you could also just call `function(D1)` if `function()` is declared properly, i.e. as above.

If it is data, it should be `const short D1[]`, and you don't need the assembler: you can provide the values in C as `const short D1[] = {...};`. The compiler should put D1 into the code segment as it is `const`.

Answer (score 0):

dspic flash sizes can be larger than 16bits. Your part has 128kb code flash. How do you want to stuff this in a 16-bit int?